# What's the equivalent of "do shell script" with javascript automations? (Yosemite)

Tags: javascript, applescript

Support for javascript automations [started with Yosemite](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW7).

How could I run using javascript an external command? (i.e. the equivalent of `do shell script` of applescript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look in the StandardAdditions.sdef.

1. Menubar menu: *Windows -> Library*
2. Double click on: **StandardAdditions**
3. Change the dropdown to **Javascript**.

You will see that many of the script command change to the  **camelHump** syntax

[image]

---

```
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

app.doShellScript('ls')
```

---

[image]

Comment: The example you give is a plain OS X executable - ls

Comment: @Mark  It is a do shell script to an external command i.e shell command not part of applescript. you can point it at any `external` command in the same way you can with Applescript `Do shell script` This is exactly what was asked for.. so what have I missed?.

Comment: It is to run a javascript method etc - I should have marked this one as the duplicate

Comment: @Mark, No it is not to run a javascript per-say. The OP wants to run a do shell script but using Javascript for Automation. As shown in my example. Do shell script are Run in Script editor which now runs Javascript or Applescript.

Comment: @Mark , note the `using javascript`

Comment: Sorry the OP wrote two questions at once and I misread them as being very similar

Comment: This is in the Javascript in Script editor. It is called Javascript not Applescript. See update.

Comment: @Mark, s'ok done that myself before

Comment: @Mark the questions seem similar but are completely distinct. Please see clarification and reopen the one marked as duplicate. Thanks

Comment: I can't find dropdown in StandardAdditions on OS X 10.9.5. Anything changed? Is it Javascript no longer supported?

Comment: @kenorb thanks for the edit. it was only introduced in 10.10