# What is the javascript equivalent of the applescript run command?

Tags: applescript, script, javascript, javascript-automation

I want to create a script for opening an app in nonstandard location quickly. With AppleScript, the app can be started with:

```
tell application [app path] to run
```

I want to do the same using javascript cause I am more familiar. But `Application([app path]).run()` does not work. In fact, the Application object does not seem to have any attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found an answer myself from [JXA-Cookbook](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/wiki/Getting-the-Application-Instance):

```js
ObjC.import('AppKit')
$.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.launchApplication('[app path]')
```

Comment: Could you please accept this answer as correct. This will help others know an answer was found

Answer (score 0):

The following works when executed in the Script Editor application.

```
var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true
app.doShellScript('open -a [app path]')
```

> Note: This answer was derived from the following question and accepted answer: [What's the equivalent of "do shell script" with javascript automations? (Yosemite)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168206/whats-the-equivalent-of-do-shell-script-with-javascript-automations-yosemit)

Comment: Thanks. It works after saving as an application bundle. But using shell for launching is a bit odd...

Comment: Your question does not include where you intended to use the javascript. So I did limited testing. The answer may appear odd, but at least the answer is simple to implement.

Comment: Actually, using `do shell script`/`doShellScript` from AppleScript/JavaScript  to execute a shell script is no more odd than using `osascript` from a shell script to execute AppleScript/JavaScript. Basically, you use which ever language or shell that works best for your needs.

Comment: In fact, I am trying to bundle the script so that it appears in the launchpad. Finally I find the solution in the jxa-cookbook. Thank you anyway.